# Python - How can I write data from/to an Excel file, then rerun the code with a new input

Tags: python, excel, selenium, xlsxwriter

im currently making a code in Python that goes onto a website, inputs texts, searches for the text, then copies over some data into an excel file. Im using xlsxwriter to do the excel part. However, I want to be able to do another search input and have the information added under the last search in the excel. I am using selenium to scrape the data off chrome.

Ultimately, I want to have my code be able to read one excel file containing a list with the input for a person's name and then occupation. these are the inputs that then give the data searched for on the web, and are stored into a separate excel file.

Im not sure how I can do the searching for inputs off of an excel file or how I can do the add the new data underneath the previously found data.

I hope this makes sense and any tips or tricks would be awesome! Im new to python by the way, so sorry if I ask anything obvious!

Comment: what have you tried so far? works better to have some code to show and have a specific problem to ask here

Comment: @Matthias I haven’t tried anything, I don’t know how to do what I’m asking for. My code is just a web scraper that pasted to excel. I guess even just suggestion a topic for me to look at could be helpful.

Comment: take some python tutorials, specifically regarding string/file processing I suppose. Or try to use search engines to find helpful articles/tutorials